# Reduce vspace in toc and set roman letters in geometry frame

Tags: table-of-contents

Hey i have two problems with my table of contents: First I would like to reduce the vspace between chapters (or sections ...). The second problem is that long roman letters in appendix are too wide outside the frame of geometry.

I found the solution for each problems, but I can solve only one problem, not both together. Maybe the two packages make problems?

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcounter{SeitenzahlSpeicher}

% Set long roman letters in geometry frame
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberbox}{\hbox}

% Reducing vspace in toc
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
beforeskip=.1em plus 1pt,
pagenumberformat=\textbf,
]{tocline}{chapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\setcounter{SeitenzahlSpeicher}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Test}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\theSeitenzahlSpeicher}
\appendix
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[50]
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Here with reducing space:

[image: Reducing space]

Here with roman letters in frame:

[image: Roman letters in frame]

When I add the solution from Pieter for section level, the dotlines are to short.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the KOMA-Script class loads package `tocbasic` automatically. So you should remove `\usepackage{tocbasic}`.

You can use `\mbox` for the page numbers in TOC, LOT and LOF with

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  pagenumberbox=\mbox
]{tocline}{
  part,chapter,
  section,subsection,subsubsection,
  paragraph,subparagraph,
  figure,table
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}% loads package tocbasic
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.1em plus 1pt
]{tocline}{chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  pagenumberbox=\mbox
]{tocline}{
  part,chapter,
  section,subsection,subsubsection,
  paragraph,subparagraph,
  figure,table
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest `\mbox` rather than `\hbox`: properly documented command versus undocumented (in the LaTeX manuals) primitive.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the hint. I have changed the command.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the `tocstyle` stuff, it is outdated, and it isn't even part of TeX Live. `tocbasic` can do it with the `pagenumberwidth` parameter. Just make it big enough that the Roman numbers fit in it.

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.1em plus 1pt,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,
  pagenumberwidth=2cm,
]{tocline}{chapter}
```

[image]

Comment: When I do this with the section level, too (because I have sections in appendix), The dotline goes not to the Roman letter. Maybe it ends 2cm before... Is there a way to change this? (I update my question with a picture)